# Why are stove jacks NOT normally made of metal?

Tags: safety, tents, stoves, winter-camping, temperature

> A [stove jack](https://www.outfitterssupply.com/Stove-Jack/productinfo/WT%20O117/) allows you to safely extend a stovepipe through the roof or
> wall of your tent. Our stove jacks are constructed of fire proof
> 17-ounce [0.48 kg] silicone-coated glass material (18" x 18" [46 cm × 46 cm]) with a solid
> silicone ring. Stove jacks are temperature rated up to 700°F (400°C).
>
> More photos [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=stove%20jack&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie_sqlvKzeAhVSmK0KHfNuAvUQ_AUIDigB&biw=1910&bih=942).

[image]

---

**Question: Why are stove jacks NOT normally made of metal?**

A. Metal would be difficult to transport.

B. Metal would conduct heat to the flammable tent fabric.

C. Something else.

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://www.wintertrekking.com/community/index.php?topic=2958.0&fbclid=IwAR2guNC_iRHfyMi6wxIiiCJl8ODFhOJ_R-NIra8YDQTw2zQ0ZyLeod0HTtM)</sup>

Comment: Having a metal stove jack defeats the purpose of having a stove jack.

Comment: Here is what [silicon fiberglass](http://www.liteoutdoors.com/product/stove-jack-material/) (from a different company) looks like.

Comment: I have a related question here: [What kind of material was used to make traditional stove jacks?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20892/what-kind-of-material-was-used-to-make-traditional-stove-jacks)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To keep your tent from burning.  Making the stove jack out of metal, would conduct heat to from your stovepipe.  This could cause your tent material to start to burn.

[If you look at the description in your link](https://www.outfitterssupply.com/Stove-Jack/productinfo/WT%20O117/)

> Our stove jacks are contructed of fire proof 17-ounce silicone-coated glass material (18" x 18") with a solid silicone ring. Stove jacks are temperature rated up to 700°F (400°C).

This material would be fire resistant and is also a poor conductor of heat (unlike metal) which would prevent your very hot stove pipe from accidentally setting your tent on fire.